How to describe a "split-screen shot" layout in traditional art terms?
If it were film or a video game I would call this type of two-frame layout a split-screen shot. What would it be called if doing a static design for print?

To take it a bit further, I have two subjects who are communicating from different places, so they are part of the same action, but in different locations. The layout needs to tie them together as one idea while also showing the boundary.
Terms that describe this in the context of comic book layouts would also be helpful. Thanks.

I'd call it... split-screen shot

@ZachSaucier Fair enough, heh. It's possible there is no other term. But sometimes you don't know what you don't know.

Far more often than not, descriptors are used instead of specific names as there's too many things to have specific names for. "Clean dividing line between two scenes" or your description are just as helpful, if not more helpful, than a specific name

Regarding comics specifically, I learned a lot from Scott McCloud's Understanding Comics back in the day. He's since written a couple more books about comics which are likely solid as well
